# Html pattern text input validation ng-pattern="/^-?[0-99]+(.[0-99]{0,2})?$/"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, ng-pattern

```
<input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^-?[0-99]+(.[0-99]{0,2})?$/" required>
```

if text box value preceed with .(dot) it should append 0(Zero) for example: **.50** => result should be **0.50** also if it is **5.** it should be **5.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-pattern="/^-?([0-9]{0,2})+(.[0-9]{0,2})?$/" Use this pattern which will allow .5 and 5. You have to have some kind of solution to handle this number in backend .ng pattern cant convert .5 to 0.5. you can use Number funtion to achive this .